# Custom helper with input validation in Codeigniter

Tags: customization, codeigniter-2, helper

My idea:

- Create a custom helper which could be loaded when checking a input
  field for min length.
- Creating it as a helper so it could be re-used    in different files
  and keeping it organized and clean.

My controller code below (application/controllers/registration.php):

- Helper "error" below is my own created helper being loaded.
- callback_min_length[2] is my attempt to send the value to the helper function

  // Load helper
          $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url', 'error'));

  ```
  // Load library
  $this->load->library('form_validation');

      // Set form rules
      $rules = array(
                     array(
                           'field'   => 'firstName', 
                           'label'   => 'firstName', 
                           'rules'   => 'callback_min_length[2]|trim'
                        )
                  );

      $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);  

      // Set custom error messages

      if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
      {
          $this->load->view('header');
          $this->load->view('view_registration');
          $this->load->view('footer');
      }
      else
      {
          $this->load->view('header');
          $this->load->view('view_registration');
          $this->load->view('footer');
      }
  ```

My custom helper code below (application/helpers/error_helper.php):

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 

    function min_length($str, $val) {

        // Load CI instance to be able to load library
        $ci =& get_instance();

        // Load library
        $ci->load->library('form_validation');

        if (preg_match("/[^0-9]/", $val)) {
            return FALSE;
        }
        if (function_exists('mb_strlen')) {
            if(mb_strlen($str) < $val) {
                $ci->form_validation->set_message('custom_min_length', 'You have to write at least ' . $val . ' characters');
                return FALSE;
            } else {
                return TRUE;
            }
        }
        if(strlen($str) < $val) {
            $ci->form_validation->set_message('custom_min_length', 'You have to write at least ' . $val . ' characters');
            return FALSE;
        } else {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
?>
```

I get no output what so ever, not even error message. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First and foremost, zero output whatsoever (aka a blank page) in PHP usually means there was a fatal error, but your error reporting is turned off. I'm not going to explain how to turn it on properly, you should be able to figure that out using Google or StackOverflow for 10 seconds.

There is a **MUCH** easier way to add a custom validation rule: extend the Form_validation library.

application/libraries/MY_Form_validation.php:

```
<?php

class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

    /**
     * Custom minimum string length validation.
     */
    public function min_strlen($input, $min_length) {

        $this->set_message('min_strlen', 'Error Message Here');

        // Your strlen logic here, returns TRUE or FALSE
    }
}
```

Seriously, that's it. No callbacks, no helpers. Your new rule is then called just like any other form validation rule, e.g.:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('field', 'My Field', 'required|min_strlen[5]|trim');
```

If you want to overwrite the default `min_length` rule with this one, just name your new method the same. It will take precedence over the original.

Something to remember: if you find yourself immediately calling and/or interacting with a CI library in your helper, the function probably belongs in the library itself.

Comment: I've been using custom functions for form validation and after reading this answer it seems the custom functions are of no use. Great answer and I assume you are a CI expert!